# Run Function when Css class changes

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to change the bordercolor of the next HTML-Element when my input is "dirty" and "valid".

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleId" formControlName="exampleId" 
[ngClass]="{  'is-valid': Form.get('exampleId')?.valid && vvtForm.get('exampleId')?.dirty) }" 
(onKeyUp)="changeBorderColorOnValidation('exampleId')">
```

JavaScript:

```
  changeBorderColorOnValidation(id) {
    if (this.Form.get(id).valid) {
      (document.querySelector('#' + id).nextSibling as HTMLElement).style.borderColor = '#28a745';
    }
  }
```

So far, this works, when you type something in the textarea the `(onKeyUp)` validates if the textarea is empty or not and changes the bordercolor.

I want to have something cleaner like `[ngRun]="functionToRun() | functionThatMustBeTrue".`

Here: 
`[ngRun]="changeBorderColorOnValidation('exampleId') | Form.get('exampleId')?.valid && vvtForm.get('exampleId')?.dirty)`

Does something like this exist?

Comment: Jan, Angular add the class ng-invalid and ng-dirty in your FomrsControls (and in your input with [ngModel)], you neen't use ngClass, just defined `.ng-invalid.ng-dyrty{border-color:'red'}` in your .css, see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes

Comment: That is for the boostrap-classes. It adds the bootstrap-class `is-valid` when the Angular classes `ng-invalid` and `ng-dirty` are true. But this still does not help me to change the border-color of THE NEXT html-element when my Angular classes `ng-valid` and `ng-dirty` are `true`.

Comment: sorry, I dont' see that you want change the class of the element NEXT, but, why not put the [ngClass] in your NEXT html-element then? else you can subscribe for the myform.get('exampleID').valuesChange or myform.get('exampleID').statusChange. NOTE: the class added by Angular are independent of bootstrap.css

Comment: That would be really easy, but that is not an option. The next Element is a TinyMCE Editor, that thing is generated automatically. In my HTML is just `<editor id="exampleID"></editor>` When I change the border-color of the style of the `<editor style="border: blue" id="exampleId">` it makes a border around the border of the TinyMCE, but it won't change the border of the TinyMCE itself. To change the border of the TinyMCE I need to select the nextSibling after the editor.

Comment: https://ibb.co/fq2kr9Y
This screenshots shows my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) and [Angular's status classes](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes):

```
.ng-invalid.ng-dirty + * {
    border-color: #28a745
}
```

Comment: I have no idea but it does not work.
When I change `editor { border: 1px solid blue; }`
This happens: [link](ibb.co/fq2kr9Y)
When I do `editor ~ * { border: 1px solid blue; }` nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, then what you want to do is already handled by angular. You just need to ad the `.ng-dirty` class to your css. See example below and check the link to angular doc below for details.

[https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes][1]

Html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleId" formControlName="exampleId"(onKeyUp)="changeBorderColorOnValidation('exampleId')">
```

Css:

```
.form-control .ng-invalid .ng-dirty {
 border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: That would work for that Input Element. But I want to change the border-color of the next element `(document.querySelector('#' + id).nextSibling as HTMLElement).style.borderColor = '#28a745';` as shown in my HTML.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Well, I don't think angular already offer you that, at least not from there docs, as far as I know, however, I think it will be more efficient to use the (change) event and run your function there instead of the (onKeyUp).  Another alternative is for you to write a custom directive to that effect, this will be neater and reusable

Comment: Already tried that, but that would only validate when you "leave" the editor, for example when you click on another element or an blank space on the page not instantly after you delete the whole text in the textbox.

Comment: I need to get the next element, because when I change the border of that element I create a border around the texteditor, I do not change the bordercolor of the editor itself... Screenshot: https://ibb.co/fq2kr9Y

Comment: Yes that is the behavior of (change) event, and I personally prefer that behavior as it reduces the number of times the function get called which I believe increase performance. If you don't want that behavior then the custom directive is the other alternative.

Comment: I also have a text that appears ngIf the textarea is ng-invalid: "Please enter some text". With (change) and that error message it would happen that the borders are still green while the error-message appears until you click elsewhere. Than the borders turned red. Did not look great.